# DRF spectacular extend_schema_view

Tags: django

what if i want to add one more list to extend_schema_view

```
list=extend_schema(
    description="The list action returns all available actions."
),
list=extend_schema(
    description="The list action returns all available actions."
),
```

)
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
pass
I have tried something like this but not working

It tried something like the above code I got error : SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: list